# XePersian stopped working after texlive-bin updated

Tags: updating, xepersian

Today an update for the package "texlive-bin" was issued by Arch Repository, and I think it was after I installed that update that my XePersian package broke. Now, I get a weird error when I try to compile the following simple document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\شروع{نوشتار}
سلام این یک آزمون است.
\پایان{نوشتار}
```

which is basically the same as the following, but with XePersian aliases:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\begin{document}
hello this is a test.
\end{document}
```

The error says:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \شروع
             {نوشتار}
```

And [here](http://pastebin.com/x4yPtAZG) is the log file generated by xelatex. The second example compiles just fine; but the first one, to which the enclosed log file belongs, is giving me troubles.

I suspect the problem is caused by some version inconsistency due to the update. But I can't find a way to get around that. I even tried downgrading "texlive-bin", which I suspected to be guilty for the inconsistency, but the problem persisted. No, I did not forget to run `texhash` afterwards.

Any ideas?

Comment: There was an update for xepersion some days ago, so I would at first suspect that this introduced the bug. Contact the author of the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added an option `[localise=on]` to my usepackage, like:

```
\usepackage[localise=on]{xepersian}
```

and it works now. I guess the new version requires it.